# How to use jQuery ajax reload the page that the user doesn't know is the page being reloaded?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I used some source on StackOverflow, but I still see the page being loaded (on the tab) when I use ajax.
I want to use ajax to reload the page without the user knowing that the page is being reloaded.

```
success: function(data){
   if(data.success == true){ // if true (1)
      setTimeout(function(){// wait for 5 secs(2)
           location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
      }, 5000); 
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you use ajax to reload the page? Just update the part of the page that changes without reloading

Comment: Because that page I use ajax update price for the product. but it relates to the discount app for the product, that discount app can only reload the page, it will update that discount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`location.reload` will result in the browser completely replacing the page (reloading it), which the user *will* be able to see unless it happens instantly. If you want things to appear as if the page has *not* been replaced, you'll have to use a different strategy.

One option is to use Javascript to fetch the new page content, and then replace it, without navigating away from the page, perhaps with [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/):

> Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched elements.

For example, if the container with information to replace is called `#container`, the:

```
$('#container').load('getContainer.php');
```

where `getContainer.php` on your server returns the updated contents of the container.

This can result in a very smooth-looking transition, since the browser is staying on the same page, and only the changed elements (if any) have been updated - everything else remains as is.

Comment: Thank you for supporting. It seems my problem has not been resolved, because it relates to the app used in the site.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no change in the page -> dont reload it.
If there is a change in the page -> you will see the changes anyway.
If you only want to see the changes -> just only reload the chaning part of the page

Comment: Thank you for supporting, it seems my problem has not been resolved, because it relates to the app used in the site.